# MacBook says out of space but disk inventory and daisy disk show plenty of space please please help

Tags: hard-drive, memory, disk-space

I have a mid 2011 MacBook air with 128 gb but from every app it says im only using 98 gb while the system has 76.45 gb that its taking that I cannot locate anywhere.
I have tried everything I can think of from listing local snapshots to putting it into recovery mode. Nothing works. I am not the most tech savvy but any way to help would be amazing.[image]

Comment: Great illustration of a full drive. When you click manage, does it help break down large files at all?

Comment: when i click manage it shows the storage i already can account for but my system still is large at 74.76 gb